# How can I make a relative layout render ontouch with orange?

Tags: android

I've made a RelativeLayout clickable, but I would like the entire layout to turn orange when the user touches it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use method described [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-layout-highlight).

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
// Layout Click enable
android:clickable="true"
// Setting Highlight Option in background property
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```